# QGLWidget image disappears after resizing window

Tags: qt, opengl, resize, qglwidget, clutter

I am working on some software to display semitransparent images in a row.

It worked fine using glut functions for resizing etc. but then i decided to move to Qt for a GUI.

all glut functions are stripped and i use a QGLWidget to render my OpenGL stuff.

When i open the program, everything works as wanted but as soon as i resize the mainwindow (and thus the QGLWidget is being resized) the contents of my openGL widget disappear or appear cluttered.

Strangely though the widget is completely grey (my glclearcolor) when there is no cluttered render of my scene content.

This is how it should look like (after starting the program):
http://abload.de/img/okw0qh0.png

And this is how it looks like after resizing the mainwindow:
http://abload.de/img/errort1peu.png
(sometimes it is just grey)

my resizeGL function looks like this and gets called properly:

```
void prosta3dwidget::resizeGL(int width, int height)
{
if (height == 0) return;                // To prevent divide by 0
    GLfloat aspect = (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height; //get aspect ratio

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
    glLoadIdentity();          
    gluPerspective(45.0f, aspect, 0.5f, 100.0f);

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    update(); //redraw content

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

Comment: Can you try calling updateGL() instead of update()?

Comment: calling updateGL() instead of update() gave me the same result. 
For some reason, resizing works with zNear in gluPerspective() set to 3 but then my scene objects disappear when i rotate them.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, noticing that this must have something to do with the depth buffer (gluPerspective manual notes that depth buffer precision is affected by zNear and zFar values: https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml )
i disabled the GL_DEPTH_TEST (uncommented glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)) and everything seems to work as desired. yet i dont fully understand why.

problem solved, new mistery achieved.